# Getting errors when trying to seed tables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, seeding, factories

When I'm trying to execute `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` command I'm getting errors. I don't understand what they are all about and I don't know what could cause them. The description of the problem is below.

Factory file PostFactory.php:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class PostFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Post::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $title = $faker->realText(rand(10, 40));
        $short_title = \Illuminate\Support\Str::length($title) > 30 ? mb_substr($title, 0, 30) . "..." : $title;
        $created = $faker->dateTimeBetween("-30days", "-1days");

        return [
            "title" => $title,
            "short_title" => $short_title,
            "author_id" => rand(1, 4),
            "descr" => $faker->realText(100, 500),
            "created_at" => $created,
            "updated_at" => $created
        ];
    }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder.php:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        \App\Models\User::factory()->count(4)->create();
        \App\Models\Post::factory()->count(15)->create();
    }
}
```

When I execute php artisan migrate:fresh --seed I'm getting those errors:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]   , ..      .
 (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a   
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.     
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]   , ..      .
 (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]   , ..      .
")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=laralove", "root", "", [])
```

I've checked the lines in the files provided in the error description but I've no clue what can be causing the errors.

Any help would be very appriciated

**UPD 0:**

I've tried to change 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' in config files as @Rwd suggested. And previous errors are gone. But now I'm getting other errors:

```
ErrorException 

  Undefined variable: faker

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\database\factories\PostFactory.php:24
     20▕      * @return array
     21▕      */
     22▕     public function definition()
     23▕     {
  ➜  24▕         $title = $faker->realText(rand(10, 40));
     25▕         $short_title = \Illuminate\Support\Str::length($title) > 30 ? mb_substr($title, 0, 30) . "..." : $title;
     26▕         $created = $faker->dateTimeBetween("-30days", "-1days");
     27▕
     28▕         return [

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\database\factories\PostFactory.php:24
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Undefined variable: faker", "C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\database\factories\PostFactory.php", [])

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory.php:385
      Database\Factories\PostFactory::definition()
```

**UPD 1:**

Replaced `$faker` with `$this->faker` as @Cristea suggested and now getting those previous errors:

```
  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]   , ..      .
")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\laralove\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=laralove", "root", "", [])
```

localhost is still changed to 127.0.0.1 in .env and database.php as @Rwd suggested

Comment: is the connection to the database working?

Comment: @Cristea yes, database.php and .env files are confingured correctly

Comment: try to change the definition values to some strings instead of vars and see what happens.

Comment: Try changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: is your MySQL server running?

Comment: "author_id" => rand(1, 4) also check out if this is reference properly.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions. I updated my question

Comment: @usrNotFound yes, it is

Comment: @Cristea I'm sorry, I didn't really get what you were trying to say. Can you please explain it more detailed?

Comment: Please share more details - to me, it looks pretty obvious that the second error is thrown, as the variable `$faker`  is not present in that `definition` method

Comment: @Cristea you mean does there really exist a foreign key named author_id? If so, then yes it does

Comment: @NicoHaase what details do you want me to share exactly?

Comment: @NicoHaase and how to fix this? I mean this file had been written by devs, and the absense of $faker was supposed to be

Comment: @NicoHaase What can cause the problem?

Comment: "The absense of $faker was supposed to be" - what does that mean? How should that script generate fixtures if Faker is absent? Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Other possible solutions:

1. you need to run ```php artisan config:cache```  anytime you change ```.env``` file.


2.  make sure the ```App\Models\Post``` has a foreign key 

 ```author_id```   or   ```user_id```  if  author table does not exists. For ex: ```public function author() {return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id'); }```


3. try to test if the connection to the database really works.
4. Check if you have more versions of mysql

Comment: @Cristea thank you so much! I did `php artisan config:cache` and fixed a line in my code where I mistakenly passed wrong argument. It was `$faker->realText(100, 400)` and now it's `$faker->realText(rand(100, 400))`. And everything worked out! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `$faker` with `$this->faker`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this, but getting other errors

Comment: Please check my lastest update in the question

Comment: But could you please explain me why I should write `$this->faker` instead of `$faker`? After doing this and writing `php artisan config:cache` It works fine now, but I really want to understand why is it so

Comment: In tutorial I watched, it's been written `$faker` and everything worked fine there (this tutorial was made 2 yrs ago, maybe something changed in Laravel)

Comment: The reason you can access it this way is because you extend the `class Factory` which has as `faker` as a property. The tutorial u are watching probably is using an older version of` laravel` and access `faker` by importing it.